# Does the Quarriors "Shaping Charm" allow me to rotate creatures to same level but with a burst (*)?

Tags: quarriors

The Shaping Charm rules state:

> Cast this Spell to rotate all Creatures in your Ready Area up 1 Level, if possible.

Although the "level" of the creature is the number in the upper left hand corner, there are "sub-levels" for some of the creatures in which the level stays the same, but they gain a * ability.  We've been playing that the order of the faces on the bottom of the card is the "Level-up" order in this situation.

Is this an acceptable interpretation? Or should we just go with numerical level only, and if there is more than one option, allow the caster to choose which +1 level face to go to?

Also, on a related note, how does this affect the Demonic Overlord which has level faces of 1, 2, and 4.  Can I roll it from 2 to 4 with a shaping charm? Or must it be exactly 1 level higher than its current level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go by the numerical level. If there is more than one option, the caster can choose which +1 Level die face to use. It is impossible for Demonic Overlord to rotate +1 Level from Level 2 (since the next level is 4), so it is unaffected. The rulebook covers what a Creature's level is.

> Creature Dice that show a Creature Icon can be “summoned.” You must spend Quiddity equal
> to the **Creature’s level (in the upper left corner of the die face)** to summon it.

Why settle for an [unofficial FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/69596/comprehensive-card-reference-and-unofficial-faq) (regardless of how nicely it is laid out):

> **[Shaping Charm](http://quarriors.wikia.com/wiki/Shaping)** - Remember the upper-left number is the Level, so a die currently has a 1 then you can rotate it to any face with a 2, or if it is a 2 you can rotate it to any face with a 3.  We don't think you can change to a different face of the same level.  We also don't think you can increase the level of a Strong Primordial Ooze.

When an example in the [rulebook](http://wizkidsgames.com/wp-content/uploads/quarma/QuarmageddonRulebook.pdf) explains a related rule, you cannot return a creature to the Ready Area on a different die face at the same level.

> **Shaping Cantrip** - Reaction: Cast this Spell to return one of your just destroyed Creatures to your Ready Area (at its same level) instead of putting it in the Used Pile.
>
> **Example:** Quinn’s beloved Scavenging Goblin has just been destroyed by a mean old Strong Deathdealer. Fortunately, Quinn has a Shaping Cantrip in his Ready Area, which he casts to save his goblin at the last moment! **Though he would like to change the goblin to a face with the Burst, he cannot rotate the die**, and must return the goblin to his Ready Area with the same (Burstless) face showing. Even though the goblin was saved, the Strong Deathdealer can still use his ability, immediately scoring Glory for his player.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this BGG post](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/688353/what-does-it-mean-to-level-up-with-the-shaping-cha), **no**.

> In the case of already being at max level, there are no legal targets and so you would not be able to turn the die at all.

If you have a die without a burst, you cannot turn it so that it is the same level with a burst. You may only turn it so that it is a level one higher. If there are multiple eligible sides to choose from, one with a burst and one without, you may choose which of those sides you'd like to turn the die to.

> In the case of multiple legal targets, you choose the result. So if you are currently Level 1 and you have the choice of Level 2 with and without burst, pick whichever side you prefer.

Comment: interesting, ok.  Then depending on your purchases, that severely limits the effectiveness of Shaping Charm.  Any word on the second question?

Comment: @Pithlit Based on a literal reading of the rules, I would say no to that as well, since it specifies the increase must be by 1 level. As you say, the value of Shaping Charm will vary by setup.